# Search mysql database table for a "float" latitude number and display the results on page

Tags: php, mysql, forms, search, latitude-longitude

What I am building is a simple form to search a MySQL database table, that at the moment searches brilliant for text names, now I need to search for a latitude number stored as a float. The table heading are name, lat and lng. When the user searches for a latitude that matches, only those results are displayed on the same page. Any help would be awesome.

```
$sql = "SELECT name,lat,lng FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%".$term."%' 
       OR lat MATCH '%".$term."%' OR lng MATCH '%".$term."%'";
```

Comment: $sql = "SELECT `name`,`lat`,`lng` FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%".$term."%' OR lat MATCH '%".$term."%' OR lng MATCH '%".$term."%'";

Comment: This is my sql query but only the 'name' works?

Comment: That's not how `MATCH`works. [See here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: I tried edited text Magnus Eriksson and I get - Warning: mysql_fetch_array() the database system using is mariaDB. Will post the other code.

Comment: while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)){  
echo 'ID: ' .$row['id'];  
echo '<br /> Name: ' .$row['name'];  
echo '<br /> Lat: '.$row['lat'];  
echo '<br /> Lng: '.$row['lng'];  
echo '<br /><br />';   
}

Comment: Thanks for all your help but fixed it by using - SELECT * FROM, it works to a degree and I can figure that out for myself. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Change the `DATATYPE` for latitude and longitude to a numeric value.  [*Representation choices*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng#representation_choices)
- Recognize whether the user is asking for lat/lng versus name.  The `OR` is killing performance almost as much as the leading wildcard.
- Use a `FULLTEXT` index, together with `MATCH(name) AGAINST('$term' in BOOLEAN MODE)` for efficient searching by name.
- Use a range; users won't enter exact lat/lng values.  Also there are rounding issues.  `lat BETWEEN $lat - 0.01 AND $lat + 0.01`.  (That's about a kilometer north/south; adjust as desired.

After you have implemented most of those, come back for some more advice/abuse.